# Which scripts were used in this cool menu?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out which scripts were used in this cool menu, in order to do something similar. Click on any item on the menu to see what I'm talking about.
http://soc.haifa.ac.il/~tkatz/

Thanks!

Comment: Right click on the page, and inspect it

Comment: just made me rethink my dynamic pagination.  thanks for finding this site!

Answer (score 3):

None. It only makes use of a carefully crafted jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function

Example

```
$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop:the_top
},1000,function(){
```

This page is a perfect example of a single page site.  All of the code is inline on the page itself.

`the_top` is set to a predefined `offset().top()` of the `div` that should be in view in the `click()` with `65` px of space for the menu bar at the top of the page.

**cool menu code**

```
$("#menu a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 

    var the_id = $(this).attr('href');
    var the_top = $("#div_"+the_id).offset().top - 65;
    highlight_menu(the_id);

    //$("#menu").animate({"top":"-=96"},500).animate({"top":"+=96"},500)

    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop:the_top
    },1000,function(){

    })
})

function highlight_menu(which)
{
    $("#menu a").removeClass('this');
    $("#menu a[href='"+which+"']").addClass('this');
    $("#ball").animate({
        "left":$("#menu a[href='"+which+"']").position().left+$("#menu a[href='"+which+"']").width()/2+17+"px"
    }, 750, function(){

    })
}
```

Comment: yep.  beat me to it.  jquery makes it too easy to look good!

Comment: lulz.  naw, u nailed it.  i'm going to make an edit to add lil somthin if you don't mind...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know wich one is on this site but I know that it can be done with Jquery LavaLamp: http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/

Comment: Thank you all. This is a great help!

Answer (score 0):

It's jquery and a little hardworking with $.scroll and $.animate and surely $.click

Answer (score 0):

there are various scripts out there:

you could try
http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/

here's how to implement it:
http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrolldeck.js/

or there's ScrollTo
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

cheers
.ben.